# Force a Scroll View to be always scrollable?

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview

I'm having a hard time dealing with a scroll view. I need to add some buttons to a LinearLayout inside of it during run time. My problem is that at the begining, that layout should be empty, but still, scrollable by the scrollview even if there isn't enough elements inside of it to be out of screen space.

Is there anyway to make this happen?

I have tried several things, but nothing seems to work.

Thank you very much in advanced.

*Please ignore textViews inside of LinearLayouts, as those are only examples of contents.

```
        <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3.15"
        android:background="@drawable/borde_negro"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/vlPentagrama"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/borde"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borde" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borde" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borde" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borde" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borde" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borde" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borde" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borde" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borde" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borde" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borde" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/borde" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Why would you do this? ScrollViews work based on the height of the content; if there's nothing *to* scroll, it won't scroll.

Comment: Yeah, I know this may sound weird, but I'll put it another way. Let's say I want my linearLayout (horizontal) to be wider than the screen in order to be able to slide my scrollview without any elements.

Could that be possible? If no, maybe you are right, and the problem is my idea, not my code.

Thanks, anyway.

Comment: I'm honestly not able to visualize what it is you're trying to do. There's `HorizontalScrollView` if you need horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Agreed, unless you have a background on the LinearLayout, without content on the LinearLayout, there would be no visual indication that the ScrollView is in fact scrolling. In any case, you could manually set the size of the LinearLayout which would enable the scroll functionality.

Comment: Guys, my problems is solved. It was something much more simple than I thougt.  TheIT's idea worked for me. Just made the LinearLayout bigger than the screen. So now I got the initial presentation I needed for my app. Please forgive me if my question was hard to understand, or even a little bit silly. Thanks, and keep being such nice people.